# Eclipse 2020-03 not opening

Tags: eclipse, java-11

I am using Java 11 so I installed eclipse 2020-03(Photon). I worked on some project and closed the eclipse,
while I reopened the it, it is creating following files without opening the IDE
core.20200508.114243.10924.0001.dmp

javacore.20200508.114243.10924.0002

Snap.20200508.114243.10924.0003.trc

jitdump.20200508.114243.10924.0004.dmp

what to do in such case.

Thank you.

Comment: You mean probably Eclipse 2020-03 which is the current version, not Eclipse Photon which is pretty old. Your Java VM crashed. Maybe your Java installation is broken. What do you get when running Eclipse from the command line? What's in the `javacore.*.txt` file?

Comment: Hi howlger,
I had 2 entries in my path AdoptOpenJDK hotspot and openJ, thts why ecliose was not opening. I removed OpenJ and now it is working.